# Fiddler - can see Client no ping to webservice - "TextView" doesn't show an envelope

Tags: http, iis, signalr

I need to start by saying this isn't my server. I am however currently troubleshooting with the company that provides the server and its service. They've stated it's our "network", though, that seems vague.
While the 'Client' is running, I'll see on Fiddler;

`<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` for "Ping"

then when the "408" error starts, I don't see the same "Envelope" message, it's completely blank.

After about 10 hours of the 'Client' being open, it will lose connection "408" to the Primary webservice and fail to the Backup webservice, never recovering to the Primary. After some time, it will also 408 on the Backup.

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Request body incomplete
Date: Sat, 22 Jan 2022 00:15:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 19:15:07.511
```

The request body did not contain the specified number of bytes. Got 0, expected 129

I also see some

```
signalR/signalr/abort?
signalR/signalr/negotiate?
signalR/signalr/connect?
signalR/signalr/start?
signalR/signalr/abort?
```

The tech said it's the "fault of the Client", but, it's their Client. I was hoping someone may be able to help me figure out "who's" problem it really is. I do have a saved Fiddler capture if that's of interest.

Also to note, I have Windows Event Viewer errors that happen at the same time.

> Error when trying to establish session on webservice with address:
> http://enps8buddy/nomwebservices3/nomwebservice82.svc.  Error:
> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
> 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

And

> GenericWSErrHandler fired:
> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
> listening at http://enps8buddy/nomwebservices3/nomwebservice82.svc
> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
> address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
> details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote
> server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a
> socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient
> buffer space or because a queue was full

I don't fully understand how this all works; I'm learning as much as I can so I can mount a better case to support. Any insight or even a point in the right direction would mean a lot to me. Thank you in advance for any consideration and time you provide.

Comment: could you check your service endpoint, is it running or not? try to set max allowed content length in iis

Comment: I did a little more messing around. I found this line of code in 1 of 2 config files for my Client. <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" /> I randomly changed the sku to 4.5, ran the client, and haven't seen an error in days. What's the significance of the sku in relation to my workstation/Client and the server/webservice?